# Place an image in the left corner of border

Tags: html, css

My problem is very simple, I want to place a small image in the corner left of my border as shown in the example below.

[image]

**My code**

```css
.description{
  border: 1px dotted black;
  position: relative;
}

.img-description{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

p{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 description">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m8s1L6J.png" class="img-description"/>
  <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```

Do you know how I could achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have this code

```
.img-description{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

You can update your top and left values to fit your idea. For example:

```
.img-description{
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
img {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply just change your Top and Left values to negative.

```
 .img-description{
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  }
```

Here it is with the new CSS code: https://jsfiddle.net/939q3rco/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use negative values for your `top` and `left` rules.

[Like this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/uxatyL1c/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add some negative `transform: translate()` for x and y.

```css
.description {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}
.img-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-5px, -5px);
}
p {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 description">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m8s1L6J.png" class="img-description" />
  <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```